# How to select last message sent between two users from mnesia

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I need to select last message sent between two users...

now with this primitive method I am selecting all messages between two users but this is long taking process

```
Guard = [{'=:=','$1',OID}],
Match = #pms{
    from = '$1',
    to   = '$2',
    body = '$3',
    _    = '_'
},

Result = ['$$'],
{ok, Result} =  mnesia:transaction(fun()->mnesia:select(pms,[{Match, Guard, [Result]}]) end),
```

check out the record

```
-record(pms,{
    message_id,from,to,body,time,seen=0}).
```

So I have two variables there, `from` and `to`  what I need is to select the last message of each conversation that user's id is either inserted into `from` or `to`

Comment: With your current table no way no process it without matching all records with specified sender and receiver

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using [qlc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/qlc.html)

I wrote some codes below may meet your requirement.

```
F = fun() ->                                                                                                                  
 Q = qlc:q([E || E <- mnesia:table(pms),E#pms.from == "a",E#pms.to == "b"]),                                     
 Q2 = qlc:keysort(2, Q, [{order, descending}]),                                                                  
 Qc = qlc:cursor(Q2),                                                                                            
 qlc:next_answers(Qc, 1)                                                                             
end,                                                                                                                    
mnesia:transaction(F).
```

Comment: this code fetches the conversation sent between you and yourself,  modified it to {E#pms.from == "a"  orelse E#pms.to == "b"} but still I need to select the last message of each conversation.

Comment: If you wan't to retrieve all conversations one time, I think you have to write some qlc codes which looks like self join in SQL.